# Split Two decimals After Dot in Google Sheets Formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I've two sets of corrupted numbers where two columns of data got merged.

1.504.99
4.604.97
18.955.00
1.154.85
0.301.82

And Like this:

0.0514.29%
0.1530.00%
0.2583.33%
0.000.00%
1.30185.71%

I want to split the each column two digits after the first dot for example 1.30185.71% as 1.30 | 185.71%

I tried split and regexreplace inside arrayformula as a noob as much as I can but as of now, nothing is working. Is there any way to make this work? Please help. Sheet is attached [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nb2iA29rLkCqlFWlAc8n1sZG3WprbME9ZDZXGWvROVU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a spreadsheet. What is your locale?

Comment: Hi, I've attached the sheet. please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

1st

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,regexextract(A2:A,"\d+\.\d{2}")))
```

and 2nd

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,regexextract(A2:A,"\d+\.\d{2}(.*)")))
```

[image]

### edit

you can add value to tranform in numeric, 1st

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,value(regexextract(A2:A,"\d+\.\d{2}"))))
```

and 2nd

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,value(regexextract(A2:A,"\d+\.\d{2}(.*)"))))
```

[image]